# Unable to generate certificate

Tags: certificates

I'm trying to generate a certificate for a certain server following [this lab](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_12.04/Crypto/Crypto_PublicKey/Crypto_PublicKey.pdf), but the command that generates a `CRT` file out of the `CSR` doesn't seem to work. See the image below

[image: Error while generating certifcate]

The command is unable to find the folder, but it exists. How do I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What did you typed in when prompted for the passphrase for ca.key ?

Comment: I solved it by changing the "~" to "/home/seed"

Comment: Please consider writing an answer stating the root cause of issue, how you found it and then fixed it. That would be helpful for community.